# How to add named not null constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add a NOT NULL constraint by the name 'NN_Grade' in existing column 'grade'.
but not able to do getting error -

My question is -

> Add a constraint (NN_Grade) in table Empl that declares column Grade NOT NULL.

My Command which I tried-

```
ALTER TABLE students ADD CONSTRAINT NN_Grade NOT NULL(adm_no);
```

Error -

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL(adm_no)' at line 1

Need guidance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE students ADD CONSTRAINT NN_Grade CHECK (adm_no IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: undeleted as per request

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make the column not nullable, i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE Empl MODIFY Grade *TYPE* NOT NULL;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f15d3)

Note that your question mentions table `Empl` whereas your answer uses `students`

Comment: Thank you for considering my problem, yes table name is changed because I am testing it on student table. Secondly I know that part what you mention in your reply but I hope you saw in question Add a constraint (NN_Grade) is clearly written which is creating problem for me. I have to give name to that constraint.

Comment: I got the reply but I have a doubt why we cannot add named constraint for NOT NULL like Primary Key

Comment: @Ric's answer shows how to add a named constraint. It is however unusual to do this for a simple constraint like `NOT NULL` - usually, the column would be marked as `NOT NULL` from the outset.